# How do you sort letters in JavaScript, with capital and lowercase letters combined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a JavaScript (jQuery's OK too if this needs it, but I doubt it will) function to alphabetize a string of letters. Let's say the string that I want to sort is: "ACBacb".

My code as of now is this:

```
var string='ACBacb';
alert(string.split('').sort().join(''));
```

This returns ABCabc. I can see why that happens, but that is not the format that I am looking for. Is there a way that I can sort it by putting the same letters next to each other, capital letter first? So when I put in ACBacb, I get AaBbCc?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Array.sort` can have a sort function as optional argument.

What about sorting the string first (ACBacbA becomes AABCabc), and then sorting it case-insensitive:

```
function case_insensitive_comp(strA, strB) {
    return strA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(strB.toLowerCase());
}

var str = 'ACBacbA';
// split the string in chunks
str = str.split("");
// sorting
str = str.sort();
str = str.sort( case_insensitive_comp )
// concatenate the chunks in one string
str = str.join("");

alert(str);
```

As per Felix suggestion, the first sort function can be omitted and merged in the second one. First, do a case-insensitive comparison between both characters. If they are equal, check their case-sensitive equivalents. Return -1 or 1 for a difference and zero for equality.

```
function compare(strA, strB) {
   var icmp = strA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(strB.toLowerCase());
   if (icmp != 0) {
       // spotted a difference when considering the locale
       return icmp;
   }
   // no difference found when considering locale, let's see whether
   // capitalization matters
   if (strA > strB) {
       return 1;
   } else if (strA < strB) {
       return -1;
   } else {
       // the characters are equal.
       return 0;
   }
}
var str = 'ACBacbA';
str = str.split('');
str = str.sort( compare );
str = str.join('');
```

Comment: argh, can't answer when kids require attention.  Nice.

Comment: `localCompare` disregards all diacritics, and shouldn't be suggested unless the OP needs this since it can have serious unintended consequences.

Comment: No function is perfect. My sorting function turns `ACBacbAäÁ` into `AAaÁäBbCc`, where your sort function would make `AaABbCcÁä` of it.

Comment: It is, without the first `str.sort()`, the result would be `AaABbCc`, and not `AAaBbCc` (note the `A`'s)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Ok, what I meant is: By using a different comparison function, one can avoid sorting the array two times. It probably does not make much of a difference in the OP's case but if you have a huge array, you don't want to call sort twice ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: added a function which takes care of that :D Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you forgot `str = str.split("");` in your second example

Comment: @Vic Fixed that and expanded the ternary operator.

Comment: split the string in chunks; `Array.from(str)` is another good option.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass a custom comparison function to [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

---

The already given answers are right so far that you have to use a custom comparison function. However you have to add an extra step to sort capital letters before lower case once:

```
function cmp(x,y) {
    if(x.toLowerCase() !== y.toLowerCase()) {
        x = x.toLowerCase();
        y = y.toLowerCase();
    }
    return x > y ? 1 : (x < y ? -1 : 0);
    // or
    // return x.localeCompare(y);
}
```

If the letters are the same, the originals have to be compared, not the lower case versions. The upper case letter is always "larger" than the lower case version.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsUy2/4/) (based on [@Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball)'s version)

Answer (score 1):

a working example http://jsfiddle.net/uGwZ3/

```
var string='ACBacb';
alert(string.split('').sort(caseInsensitiveSort).join(''));

function caseInsensitiveSort(a, b)
{
   var ret = 0;
   a = a.toLowerCase();b = b.toLowerCase();
   if(a > b)
      ret = 1;
   if(a < b)
      ret = -1;
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I see, really useful tip for new comer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom sort function like this:

```
function customSortfunc(a,b){ 
  var lca = a.toLowerCase(), lcb = b.toLowerCase();
   return lca > lcb ? 1 : lca < lcb ? -1 : 0;

}
var string='ACBacb';
alert(string.split('').sort(customSortfunc).join(''));
```

You can read more about the sort function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

**Beware**: if you use `localeCompare` like other answer suggests "u" and "ü" will be sorted together as the same letter, since it disregards all diacritics.

Comment: No function is perfect. Your sorting function turns `ACBacbAäÁ` into `AaABbCcÁä`, where my sort function would make `AAaÁäBbCc` of it.

Comment: Would appending all diacritics after the other characters be better then? I don't think so.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: You are of course right, my point is that many languages has letters outside the a-z range, and the use of localeCompare breaks sorting in them all. This is something that programmers from English speaking countries (almost) always forgets. Being from one of the countries with letters outside the a-z range, i am used to this problem.

Comment: @Martin, how DO you handle this problem?

Comment: How exactly would many languages be broken by `localeCompare`? Using `<` and `>` is a binary comparison. By the way, do you mean languages like German, Spain or Dutch (ë, à, ..)? Languages like Chinese and Japenese will be broken in such a way I do not know how to handle it :o

Comment: @Pete Wilson: The easiest way to handle it, if you need to support all languages is to sort serverside using localization, and forget about sorting clientside - javascript simply isn't up to the task without a ridiculous overhead of logic and data tables. If you just need to support European languages it is fairly trivial with a small lookup hash.

Comment: @Lekenstein: I mean most non-english European languages. Languages based on non-latin charsets is a whole other can of worms - ever tried sorting Cyrillic or greek using js? I can tell you it is no fun. Throw rtl languages into the mix and it is a regular headache. My point was never that the solution i gave will fit everything, but using localeCompare breaks any chance you have of handling non-english.

Comment: @Lenkenstein: As a side note, have you ever seen a major spec site that details how localeCompare works for non a-z letters? MDC doesn't neither does the MSDN library. Are you even sure that they use the same logic? Maybe it's just me, but i avoid localeCompare like the plague unless i really really need diacritic-ignorant sorting in js, which, tbh, i very rarely do.

Answer (score 0):

basic example for another replace, combined with lowercase :D

```html
   

<button onclick="myFunction('U')">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
    var str = "HELLO WORLD!";
    var res = str.toLowerCase().split("o");
    var elem = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
    for(i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        (i > 0)?elem += val + res[i]:elem += res[i];
    }
}
</script>
```